# How can I pass parameters and uploading image at the same time to One web api?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, image-uploading

### I use this controller:

```
 public class uploadphotosController : ApiController
    {
        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post( )
        {

            // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            string root =HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/photos");//Burdaki app data klasoru degisecek
            var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

            // Read the form data and return an async task.
            var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
                ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t =>
                {
                    if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                    {
                        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, t.Exception);
                    }

                    // This illustrates how to get the file names.
                    foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
                    {

                        string fileName = file.LocalFileName;
                        string originalName = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;


                        FileInfo file2 = new FileInfo(fileName);
                        file2.CopyTo(Path.Combine(root, originalName.TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"')), true);
                        file2.Delete();

                        //Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                        // Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
                    }
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                });


            return task;
        }

    }
```

### And I use this in WebApiConfig.cs

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "DefaultApi_uploadphotos",
             routeTemplate: "api/{ext}/uploadphotos/",
             defaults: new
             {
                 controller = "uploadphotos"
             });
```

It works fine, but I need to upload image with send email and password at the same time. Because I want to upload image if a user is exists. In my way everyone uploads photo as a user or not. I want to send image and some parameters like email and passwords to the same web api.

How can I do that?

thanks in advance

Comment: you should be able to use query parameters `?email=email&password=pw` and then you should use HTTPS since you're passing passwords in clear text (at least I presume)

Comment: I cant understand , please give a sample ?

Comment: your Post can take parameters `Post(string email, string pw)` then you can access those in your body, post to url with query params like so `http://yoursite.com/uploadphotos?email=whatever&pw=b4df00d` and the image attachments

Comment: so  public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post( ) should be Post(String email,String password) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile(string a, string b)
{
     var requestStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
  ...
}
```

Routing:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerApi",
    routeTemplate: "/{controller}/{a}/{b}"
);
```

Sending file:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create("http://host/controller/hello/world");
request.Method = "POST";
var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
var docFile = File.OpenRead(sourceFile);
docFile.CopyTo(stream);
docFile.Close();
stream.Close();
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: what is  **var requestStream** ? how can I reach parameters in web api side

Comment: It should be **Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile(...)** or I can be **Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(...)** ?

Comment: I try it and It gives this error **404 not found** (conn.getResponseMessage())

Comment: "hello" will be stored in string a and "world" will be stored in string b. You can just use Post or PostXY. requestStream is the Stream of your file.

Comment: regarding 404: did you set the right value for host/controller ?

Comment: I set it like this **public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(string email, string password)** but when I upload photo it gives that error

Comment: I use android to send image and at the same time 2 parameters

Comment: Well I don't know why isn't working with your code :-) is the route correct? Is the post url correct? maybe it helps if you first try to send a file from a .net console app and then translate that bit to "android".